# i want to retrieve multiple images from sql and print it in jsp page in a specified position

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<html>
<% 
byte[] imgData = null;
%>
<%
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con =  
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/try","root","root");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from employee ");

while (rs.next()) {
Blob image = rs.getBlob(1);
imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());
 }
// display the image
response.setContentType("image/png");
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
%>

<img="<%o.write(imgData);%>" width="10" height="20">
<%o.flush();
o.close();

out.println("hi");
rs.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
out.println("Unable To Display image");
out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());
return;
} 

%>
```

This code prints the image to the size of the image. I cant adjust the image size. I have tried many methods.

If i can extract image from any other form the please help

Comment: Does this happen to display the image on the page you want or on a new page all by itself?

Comment: it is displaying in new page if i print something on the output screen it is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think you should probably create a separate jsppage for the sole purpose of outputting the image. Then, on this page, within your while loop you need to set the image URL of the  tag as follows. I can't guarantee that this code will work (I'm not accustomed to JSP) but the general the approach should work

JSP page to generate the image (Call this GetImage.jsp):

```
    <%@ Page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ Page import="java.io.*" %>

    <html>
    <%
    byte[] imgData = null;
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =  
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/try","root","root");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from employee where employee_id=" + request.getParameter("empId"));
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            Blob image = rs.getBlob(1);
            imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());
        }
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
        o.flush();
        o.close();
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        out.println("Unable To Display image");
        out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    } 
    %>
    </html>
```

JSP page to list employee images (Call this EmployeeList.jsp):

```
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
    <html>
    <%
    try 
    {
        String EmpFirstName;
        String EmpSurname;
        String EmpId;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/try","root","root");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select employee_id,first_name,surname from employee");
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            EmpFirstName = rs.getString("first_name");
            EmpSurname = rs.getString("surname");
            EmpId = rs.getString("EmpId");
            <DIV><%=EmpFirstName5> <%=Surname%> </DIV>
            <img src="http://localhost/GetImage.jsp?empId=<%=EmpId%>" />
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        out.println(e.Message);
        return;
    } 
    %>
    </html>
```

So in your new page you would accept a parameter representing the employee id (via querystring or otherwise). On that page you would then query the DB for the image for that specific employee id and do as you were doing - without the while loop.

The problem with your code above is that it is setting the outputstream for the whole page to be the image.

Comment: is there any way to do the same in the jsp, by correcting the outputstream

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer. I have done my best to code it as I would think it should work. I don't have access to test JSP so you will have to take it the rest of the way. Essentially, you have 2 pages.One page loops through the list of employees and outputs their name and surname and generates an image tag for them with the *src* parameter set to the url of the new GetImage.jsp page - to which we are appending the employee_id from our loop. Hope this helps. If not, theres no more I can do, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is code is for dynamically displaying images in jsp.






<%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="cyan">
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","nag","nag");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
String query="select * from EMP";
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
sb.append("D://TestImages//");
sb.append("image");
String path;
%>
    <table  border="1" cellpadding="5"><tr><td>Id</td><td>Name</td> 
    <%
    while(rs.next())
    { 
        int count=1;
        sb.append(count);
        Blob b=rs.getBlob(2);
        count+=1;
        path=sb.toString();
        byte baa[]=b.getBytes(1, (int)b.length());
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(path+".jpeg");
        fos.write(baa);
        fos.close();
        %>
        <tr>
        <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
        <td><img alt="" src="<%=path+".jpeg"%>"></td>
    </tr>
    <% 
    }
    %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```